# Issue with Initializing OpenAI Client in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, openai-api

I'm working on a Node.js/Typescript project that involves using the OpenAI API with the `openai` package. I'm facing an issue with initializing the OpenAI client in my code. Below is the relevant part of my code where I'm initializing it:

```js
import OpenAI from 'openai';

class AssistantController {
  public openai: OpenAI;

  constructor() {
    this.openai = new OpenAI({ apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY as string });
  }

  // Other methods...
}
```

The problem is that the this.openai client does not seem to be correctly initialized, leading to errors like "Cannot read properties of undefined."

I'm initializing the OpenAI client within the constructor, which appears to be the correct way to do it. However, when I try to use it in other methods within the class, it's not recognized, resulting in the mentioned errors.

I've double-checked the installation and the code, but I can't identify the root cause of this issue.

*Additional Information* :

**Node.js version: v20.11.0**

**OpenAI package version: 4.25.0**

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.